# Filtering inner mechanism

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Name="Filtering" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
    Checked="AddFiltering" Unchecked="RemoveFiltering" 
    Margin="8" Style="{StaticResource checkBoxStyle}">Show only bargains</CheckBox>
```

I have AddFiltering method:

```
private void AddFiltering(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    listingDataView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyBargainsFilter);   

}
```

I have ShowOnlyBargains method:

```
private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    AuctionItem product = e.Item as AuctionItem;
    if (product != null)
    {
        // Filter out products with price 25 or above
        if (product.CurrentPrice < 25)
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I also have a problem here :-)

ShowOnlyBargainsFilter returns void.
All it changes really is argument value i.e:

e.Accepted = true;

I guess that this change is sent back to some kind of a caller?
How does it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You obviously got the code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx), so I will try to explain how this works. Note that if you use Reflector on the `CollectionViewSource`, the code will likely be different, as this is just a rough guess at what they are doing.

So, since .NET (C#) passes objects by reference, when the event is raised, you will be modifying the same object that the original `CollectionViewSource` sent in the event. This means that it can read the state after all `EventHandler`s have completed. That means it can have filtering code something like this:

```
private void ApplyFilter()
{
    List<object> acceptedItems = new List<object>();

    foreach (object o in this.innerCollection)
    {
        FilterEventArgs e = new FilterEventArgs(o);
        Filter(this, e); // raise the Filter event
        if (e.Accepted)
            acceptedItems.Add(o);
    }

    this.filteredItems = acceptedItems;
}
```

When the `CollectionViewSource` raises the `Filter` event, any event handler registered with the event will be called. Events in .NET are a concept that is described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) also. That link is from the first version of .NET, but is still applicable. If you want more information, you can also look up multicast delegates, as the event is a special case of a multicast delegate.

Answer (score 1):

C# is a reference based system. So you change the obejct "e" by reference. So the object which is given as the Parameter will be changed direct.

Hiere a short example:

```
namespace Streamtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test cTest = new Test();
            cTest.Name = "Hello!";

            Do(cTest);

            Console.WriteLine(cTest.Name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Do(Test Test)
        {
            Test.Name = Test.Name + " " + Test.Name;
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that it is reference being used here but I do not understand what is calling 'ShowOnlyBargainsFilter' here.

Comment: the question here is who olds a reference to e